# Split string after comma and x number of characters

Tags: c#, string, split

I am trying to get the first 6 characters in a string after the last comma.   I'm splitting the string just fine, and I added for 6 characters, but my results are now including the 6 characters and the comma.

I have input similar to this: "VILLEDA URIBE,PAUL,BU2960"

I basically use this, and it works fine:

```
string last = str.Substring(str.LastIndexOf(',') + 1);
```

I'll get an output of BU2960, which is fine.

My problem is sometimes my input is like this: "BENTANCOURT,MARIA,BU2960_1_1"

I only want the 6 characters after the last comma.  I've tried this:

```
string last = str.Substring(str.LastIndexOf(','), 6 + 1);
```

But now my results include the comma.  So my output is this `,BU2690`

Not sure exactly how to make this work where I get the 6 characters after the comma as my output.

Comment: That is probably a good idea though I should always have a comma and at least 6 characters after the comma.

Comment: The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?view=net-5.0#System_String_Substring_System_Int32_System_Int32_) are your friend =D. That first parameter of substring wants the start index of your substring, so, by inserting the index of the last comma, you are including the comma.

Looks like you got your own answer solved, but, docs are the key here. I need daily reminders of it myself.

Comment: So i was just told I can't include the "BU" part in my result.   So I need to split after the comma and the characters BU so the result is 2690.  I had hopped maybe 
string last = str.Substring(str.LastIndexOf(',BU'), + 1, 4);   Would work, but I get a compile error that too many chatacters in the character literal..    Should have known wouldn't be that simple.

Comment: The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.lastindexof?view=net-5.0#System_String_LastIndexOf_System_String_) are your friend =D. That will in fact work, but, in that code you are attempting to put a string value into a character literal. Change your single quotes to double quotes around ",BU" and you'll be golden.

Comment: @steamrolla That got rid of my literal.  Now though the output is still including "BU"
Value.LastIndexOf(",BU") + 1, 4);

Apologies I am not a devleoper, and do not pretend to be one on TV...

Comment: I'm a moron...  the "+1" is because I'm getting the characters immediately after the ",".  If I want it to look after ",BU" it needs to be a +3...    Thanks for the help @steamrolla

Answer (score 2):

I resolved this almost immediately after posting the question. I needed to swap the ",6" after the "+ 1" so the code is:

```
string last = str.Substring(str.LastIndexOf(',') + 1, 6);
```